# gfortran (mac os x) : Error: Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions

Tags: arrays, macos, fortran, gfortran, fortran2008

I am using El Capitan 10.11.6 and installed gcc 6.1.0 from homebrew. I have a Fortran program test.f that has >7 dimensional arrays. I compiled using

```
gfortran -std=f2008 test.f
```

I thought Fortran 2008 handles arrays up to dimension 15. However, I still get the following:

```
Error: Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think that flag tells `fortran` to accept Fortran 2008 syntax and constructs to the extent that it implements them.  But it doesn't magically cause the compiler to implement all 2008 features.  There are some sources of information about which compilers implement which features, including http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status.  Have a look.

Comment: Thanks! The site doesn't show which compilers handle >7 arrays. Do you know what free compilers can I use on Mac OS X that handle >7 arrays?

Comment: If it ain't in that list it ain't a Fortran compiler, at least not one currently available.  Get out your chequebook.

Comment: It does show which compilers do handle >7 arrays, it is the line "Maximum rank + corank ≤ 15". Specifics for GCC are found in https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status. You might want to give openuh a go: http://web.cs.uh.edu/~openuh/, though it's mainly focussing on coarrays. I have no idea whether they support more than 7 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

With version gfortran 8.1.0, it works with `-std=f2008` compilation flag

```
program test
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
real(kind=dp) :: vec(2,3,3,6,2,3,12,8)
end program
```

One compiles this test program with

```
gfortran -std=f2008 test.f90 -o test
```

Comment: `kind=8` is UGLY.